# search files in python based on header and footer patterns

Tags: python

I would like to parse a file which looks like this:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA


AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
HEADER
body
body
body
FOOTER
BLABLABLABLA
BLABLABLABLA
BLABLABLABLA
```

I would like to extract the content that exists between HEADER and FOOTER.
The number of lines between each HEADER and FOOTER can vary and so can the content itself
I have written the following code to extract this:

```
   fd=open(file,"r")
    for line in fd:
        if not start_flag:
            match = re.search(r'.*HEADER.*',line)
            if not match:
                continue
            else:
                body=body+line+"\n"
                start_flag=True
        else:
            match_end = re.search(r'.*FOOTER.*',line)
            if not match_end:
                body=body+line+"\n"
                continue
            else:
                body=body+line+"\n\n"
                break
   print body
```

Is this the best way to go about extracting contents from file using python ?
What are the other ways to go about such a problem ?

Comment: Maybe more suited to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby

with open(f, "r") as fin:
    groups = groupby(fin, key=lambda k:k.strip() in ("HEADER", "FOOTER"))
    any(k for k,g in groups)
    content = list(next(groups)[1])
print content
```

Comment: Only if you're trying to win an obfuscated code contest. It's also not clear at all how efficient this is. Look at Joel's answer below. Much clearer, and very efficient.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, are you insinuating that this is less efficient?

Comment: I'm insinuating that I can't tell. The "dropwhile" and "takewhile" code obviously only passes through the iteration once and doesn't make any unnecessary copies of the data. I can't tell whether yours does or not, but I suspect it might. Both your code and Joel's have what seems to me an unnecessary `list()`, so it might not be that much better.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, There isn't that much code. Which part do you suspect is iterating the file multiple times?

Comment: No, it's not making more than one pass over the file. But I think it might be making internal lists in memory. Again, I don't really know, and that's my point. I can't see what is happening here. I can't tell what that `any()` is doing at all.  I just don't know.  I'm not 100% in the no-comments school, but I am of the school that if you can't tell what the code is doing without comments, maybe there's a better way to do it.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: The `list()` call is for demonstrative purposes, as in, "let me print the contents of the result to show that it indeed worked". In practice, you might or might not do a list conversion, depending on what you needed to do with the data.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way using `itertools`:

```
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile

with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    starting_iterator = dropwhile(lambda x: x.strip() != 'HEADER', f)
    next(starting_iterator, None)
    contents = takewhile(lambda x: x.strip() != 'FOOTER', starting_iterator)    
    print list(contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I got pushback on my comments, I might as well show how I'd do it (no need to build lists in memory--that's what iterators are for:

```
import itertools as it

def contents(source):
    return it.takewhile(lambda x: "FOOTER" != x.strip(),
        it.islice(
            it.dropwhile(lambda x: "HEADER" != x.strip(), source),
        1, None) )

with open("testfile") as f:
    for line in contents(f):
        # Do your stuff here....
```